# GLSL and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opengl-es-2.0

This is bit complicated to ask but I want to use GLSL as for pre-processing and then use OpenCV for post-processing. Basically, I used my texture as an input to GLSL shader and whatever fragment shader outputs, I have to use that as an input to to OpenCV.
After `gl_FragColor`, I used `glReadPixels` to read FBO and then set that data as `IplImage` in OpenCV.

```
GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[640*480*4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, 640,480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),IPL_DEPTH_8U,4);
cvSetData(img,pixels,640*4);
```

It works perfect but the major problem is that it's really slow.
Is there any other way to set the output of my fragment shader (`gl_FragColor`) to `IplImage` in fast way or in other words, directly? I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 so there are some limitations.

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't post this as an answer because I am not completely sure. You have the OpenCV_GPU package, which is CUDA based. It is possible to use the GLSL output as CUDA input, although I do not know anything of that other than that it is tricky. The basic problem is that OpenCV is CPU based, and GLSL is GPU. This means that you simply have to transfer the data to different memories. So, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Uhm, you're allocating a 320x240 buffer and trying to read a 640x480 image into it? Consider your heap smashed...

Comment: @kusma 320*240*4 == 640*480 == 307200. No smashing... :)

Comment: @mevatron But 640*480 != 640*480*4. Indeed smashing!

Comment: @mevatron Yes, and pixels is of size 320*240*4 into which `glReadPixels` tries to read a 640*480*4 image. So how should this work?

Comment: Ah...I missed that :), so `new GLubyte[320*240*4]` should be `new GLubyte[640*480*4]`, I didn't notice the `GL_RGBA` at first :)

Comment: Ahh I made a mistake when I typed this. It wasn't the main problem in here. I originally have 640*480*4 on my program and I messed up while I was typing in here. Thanks for pointing out and I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used GLSL before, so there may be a reason you can't do this. But, have you considered removing one of the memory copies like this:

```
Mat_<Vec4b> glslImage(640, 480);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 640, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLubyte*)glslImage.data);
```

Is there a reason you have to use the temporary `pixels` buffer?

Comment: Thanks. It works but still, it does not really affect/improve the speed :(